# Order columns in migrations EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

'I'm working on an `EF Core` application where I inherit a common class in an `entity`. When I migrate and update the database, the inherited columns get created in the first place and the properties of the entity comes next.

Just curious, I wanted to know if it is possible to automate the way to set the order of column creation in the SQL table.

//Code:

```
public class Employee: BasicEntity
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Name can't be longer than 60 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Age is required")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "DOB is required")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public int City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    public int State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
    public int Country { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You can change the order in migration code.

Comment: Check this link : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use data annotation for column order in EF core using [Column(Order=)]

```html
public class Employee: BasicEntity
    {
        [Column(Order=0)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Name can't be longer than 60 characters")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(Order=1)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Age is required")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Column(Order=2)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "DOB is required")]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
        public int City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
        public int State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
        public int Country { get; set; }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, EF Core does not support explicit column ordering. There is a lot of discussion about this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2272

You can use this solution to add support for explicit column ordering to your project: https://github.com/premchandrasingh/EFCoreColumnOrder. This solution adds the HasColumnOrder extension method. There is an example of use in the Sample folder. Do not forget to replace the corresponding services in your DbContext.

Also, you can manually arrange the columns in the correct order in the EF migration.

Comment: is there any solution for postgre-sql migration?

Comment: You can use the EFCoreColumnOrder solution mentioned here if you replace the CustomAnnotationProvider with your own implementation derived from NpgsqlMigrationsAnnotationProvider and the CustomSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator derived from NpgsqlMigrationsSqlGenerator.